# Eclipse: Build and conform to different JRE versions

Tags: eclipse, java

Is there a way to build my app using one version of the JRE but have my source conform to another version?

I would like to debug my app locally using 1.6 because OS X's 1.6 is much better than 1.4.2, but because of backwards compatibility reasons we actually ship using 1.4.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manage this though the Run Configurations options. Create a new Run Configuration --> Java Application and then you can specify the JRE you want to use for that configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Or can change your Run configuration, but you can also change your project properties to do this too so any class you decide to run will do this.