# How Can I Tell Eclipse to Compile and Build a Project with a Different JRE Version than it Normally Does?

Tags: eclipse, java, java-5

I'm not sure if this question has been answered in full or if my title is descriptive enough given my situation, but I've been asked to convert a project from being built with Ant to Maven. That part isn't too bad, but I've been told that this application was designed specifically for the JRE version 1.5 rather than the JRE 6 everything else I've been dealing with uses. Now, I'm incredibly new to Eclipse and Java themselves, so I was a bit confused when I was asked to tell either Eclipse or Maven to build this particular project using the JRE 1.5 instead. I have it installed, I believe, and I've tried to follow the steps outlined here: ( [Eclipse: Build and conform to different JRE versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619560/eclipse-build-and-conform-to-different-jre-versions) ), but I've run into a snag.

I've managed to change the Run Configuration to use the Alternate JRE jre1.5.0_11. When I then tried to build it, the console spat out the following:

```
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.5.0_11\..\lib\tools.jar
[ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
[ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
[ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
[ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
```

I assume this means that I need to be using the JDK 1.5 in order to use the JRE 1.5, since I'm currently working with JDK 1.6. Now, is there a way to install the JDK 1.5 so that this project can use it? My JAVA_HOME variable currently points to the JDK 1.6, and I would like it to stay that way... Is there a way to be able to use both and simply tell the project (or Eclipse or Maven... however it works) to use a specific version of the JDK?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can install as many different versions of Java — JREs and JDKs — as you like, and tell Eclipse which one to use for each project.

First step is to install the JDK 1.5 on your machine (JDK is short for 'Java [SE] Development Kit', look for that on the Oracle download site). The JDK includes a JRE, so to make life easier you can usually just install the JDK and not worry about the JRE/JDK distinction.

Second step is to tell Eclipse about the new JDK. Go to *Preferences...* then *Java* > *Installed JREs*. Click the *Search...* button and Eclipse should find your newly installed JDK 1.5 and add it to the list.

Final step is to allocate that JDK 1.5 to your project. Bring up the *Properties* menu for your project (right-click it). Then set these values:

- *Java Compiler* tab

  - Tick *Enable project specific settings*
  - Set *Compiler Compliance level* to *1.5*
- *Java Build Path* tab, *Libraries* subtab

  - Find the *JRE System Library* item, click *Edit...*
  - Set *Alternate JRE* to your newly installed JDK 1.5

Comment: I've performed all of these steps, and it still tells me to "ensure I am using JDK 1.4 or above and not a JRE." Everything looks correct in the preferences and the properties, but it's still not working. It was `unable to locate the Javac Compiler in: c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.5.0_11\..\lib\tools.jar`. EDIT: Nevermind, fixed it. The run configuration was trying to use the JRE and not the JDK. Changed that, and it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using JRE 1.5 rather than JDK 1.5

Make sure you download the JDK 1.5 and your issue should go away. You can set the default JDK in the preferences, search for 'jre'.

Projects can also define their specific jre

Get JDK 1.5 from Here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html

Comment: I'm new to Java, so I get a bit confused on the JDK's and JRE's. Are both necessary in this case? Is there a way to keep my default JDK to 1.6 (since all of our other applications use it) and simply tell specific projects to use JDK and JRE 1.5?

Comment: ok, jre is just the runtime, jdk is the software development tool (with the compiler that eclipse needs). JDK comes with JRE.. but JRE doesn't come with all the JDK tool.. does it make sense ?

Comment: Yeah, I understand that part now. So is there a way to have both JDK 1.5 and JDK 1.6, leaving the later as the default and simply telling it to use JDK 1.5 for specific projects? I noticed I can change which JRE version to use, so in doing so, does that also inherently specify which JDK version to use?

Comment: hum, not exactly: you can tell a project to compile with JDK 1.6 but to generate code for 1.5. the JRE in preferences is the default one, but if you right click on your project folder, then properties(if I recall), you can override the compilation settings