# ODBC Connectivity with java application

Tags: java, odbc, ms-access-2007

I am creating a login dextop application in JAVA. For DATABASE I am using **MICROSOFT ACCESS 2007**.
So I need to use ODBC connectivity to use database in my application. 
Here are the steps I am following to make connection :-

1.Click Start, and then click Control Panel.

2.In the Control Panel, double-click Administrative Tools.

3.In the Administrative Tools dialog box, double-click Data Sources (ODBC).The ODBC Data Source Administrator dialog box appears.

4.Click User DSN, System DSN,

But here, in System DSN, There is no option to choose to select. 
Please help me out of this and give your valuable suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java connection to ms access 2010 database in windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751308/java-connection-to-ms-access-2010-database-in-windows-7)

Comment: how can I knw that which version of ms access I am using sir??

Comment: What really matters is whether your Java application is running as 32-bit or 64-bit. The "bitness" of the ODBC driver and DSN must match the "bitness" of the application that is using it.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue, I am using **window -7, 64-bit machine** 
so i just did one thing..

right click Data source (ODBC)..go to properties change the folloing thing

**target [ %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe ]**

**start in : [ %SystemRoot%\System32 ]**

press enter and continue as admin. :) enjoy.. :)

Comment: It is a temporary "repair". On other machines this link leads to 64 bit version of `odbcad32.exe`. IMO it is safer to just create 2nd link that leads to 32 bit version of `odbcad32.exe` and name those links with "bitness". This is how MS should do it: `odbcad32.exe` and `odbcad64.exe`.