# "Could not find the main class. The program will exit"

Tags: java, eclipse

I m trying to test sending email in java using java6. The code is this:

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Sending_email {

final String senderEmail = "ttttt@gmail.com";
final String senderPassword = "123456";
final String emailSMTPserver = "smtp.gmail.com";
final String emailServerPort = "587";
String receiverEmail = null;
String emailSubject = null;
String emailBody = null;

public Sending_email(String receiverEmail, String Subject, String message) {
    this.receiverEmail = receiverEmail;
    this.emailSubject = Subject;
    this.emailBody = message;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", senderEmail);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", emailSMTPserver);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", emailServerPort);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", emailServerPort);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

    //SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();

    try {
        Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);

        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setText(emailBody);
        msg.setSubject(emailSubject);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderEmail));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(receiverEmail));
        Transport.send(msg);
        System.out.println("send successfully");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("Error occurred while sending.!");
    }

}

private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(senderEmail, senderPassword);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Sending_email("tttt@gmail.com", "suerjanct", "erjan lsjflsjdfsldjf");
}
```

}

However, Eclipse can't compile it. It says

"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javax/mail/Authenticator : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0"

51.0 means I run jdk 1.7. but I only have 1.8 and 1.6 installed on my computer!
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have used higher `JDK` during compile time and lower JDK during `runtime`, as you said you have  java 1.8, try to compile the code using the same

Comment: hmm, this is strange! I put in my project settings to run & compile using java6 explicitly. How do i check if it compiles using java6 not8?

Comment: the funny thing, the eclipse now runs itself on java8, but this should not be a problem, cuz for project settings i put jre6 everywhere...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302687/how-can-i-tell-eclipse-to-compile-and-build-a-project-with-a-different-jre-versi